# On a modified least square.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, convex-optimization, regression

Given a vector $y \in \mathbb R^n$ and real **constants** $x_{ij}$ ($i=1,\dots,n$, $j=1,\dots,p$), we consider a vector $\beta = (\beta_0,\dots,\beta_p)$ which minimize
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\Bigl(y_i-\beta_0-\sum_{j=1}^p \beta_jx_{ij} \Bigr)^2 + \lambda\sum_{j=1}^p\beta_i^2.$$
Here $\lambda$ is a nonnegative parameter. (Thus $\beta$ depends on $\lambda$.)

It seems to be known that finding $\beta$ is equivalent to the following problem:
$$\text{minimize}\ \ \sum_{i=1}^n\Bigl(y_i-\beta_0-\sum_{j=1}^p \beta_jx_{ij} \Bigr)^2 \quad\text{subject to}\quad \sum_{j=1}^p\beta_i^2 \leq s.$$

**How can we prove the equivalence?**

Notes

1. I am NOT asking how to find $\beta$.
2. As notation suggests, I found this statement in a context of ridge regression.

Comment: This is a case of [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions), so the statement can be proven either by demonstrating that the constraints satisfy [the conditions for KKT conditions to be sufficient for optimality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Sufficient_conditions), or directly by adapting the general proof (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X99964843, http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00941316).

Comment: Actually the dual problem of ridge regression is $\min \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n\Bigl(y_i-\beta_0-\sum_{j=1}^p \beta_jx_{ij} \Bigr)^2\bigg)$ subject to $\sum_{j=1}^p\beta_i^2=0$

Comment: @Budenn Thank you for the information. I'll look at details.

Comment: @OccupyGezi Do you mean "$=s$" in the condition?

Comment: Right. Check the pages 25-26-27 in this link http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mls/lecture_8.pdf

Comment: But if $\sum_{j=1}^p \beta_i^2=0$, then $\beta_i=0 \ \forall \ i$. $\quad$ Only if p=1, then $\beta_1$ can be something different.

Comment: @OccupyGezi, that cannot be correct. Your model forces $\beta_i\equiv 0$.

Comment: Note that $s$ and $\lambda$ are different quantities. There is not a simple formula to give you the "equivalent" value of $s$ given $\lambda$, or vice versa. These are equivalent only because they generate the exact same tradeoff curves between $\sum_i (y_i-\beta_0-\sum_j \beta_j x_{ij})^2$ and $\sum_j \beta_j^2$.

Comment: I found a direct argument:  https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/16-kkt.pdf page 19.